# Selecting a portion of text in html Using Java

Tags: java, html, parsing, xpath, jsoup

I have looked through multiple forms before asking this question.Basically, what i need is to select part of the text in a HTML file. the html is constructed something like this

```
<div class = "pane big">
<code>
<pre>
SomeText
<a id="par1" href="#par1">¶</a>
MoreText
.
.
.
<a id="par2" href="#par2">¶</a>
MoreText
</pre>
</code>
</div>
```

So what i need to do, is to extract the text under the href tag par1 by itself and then get the text under par2 href tag separately. i tried to use Jsoup but all i could do is to select the whole text withing the div. Also tried XPath but the expression that I'm evaluating is not accepted. not sure maybe because it's not an XML file to begin with.

and example of XPath expressions that I used is .

```
/html/body/div/div[2]/code[2]/pre/text()[3]
```

and CSS

```
body > div > div.pane.big > code:nth-child(7) > pre
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do that with pure CSS selectors, additional extracting and appending logic in Java code needed:

1. Select **pre** element
2. Split it to sequence of text parts by **a** element as splitter.
3. Skip 1st element and join two (or more) next parts.

Here simple code sample for that (JDK 1.8 style with stream API and old JDK 1.5 - 1.7 style):

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import static java.util.Arrays.stream;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;

public class SimpleParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final Document document = Jsoup.parse(new File("div.html"), "UTF-8");
        final Elements elements = document.select("div.pane.big pre");

        System.out.println("JDK 1.8 style");
        System.out.println(
                stream(elements.html().split("\\s+<a.+</a>\\s+"))
                        .skip(1)
                        .collect(joining("\n")
                        ));

        System.out.println("\nJDK 1.7 style");
        String[] textParts = elements.html().split("\\s+<a.+</a>\\s+");
        StringBuilder resultText = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 1; i < textParts.length; i++) {
            resultText.append(textParts[i] + "\n");
        }
        System.out.println(resultText.toString());
    }
}
```

P.S. Note that last tag *div* in your HTML code sample should be closed-tag.

Answer (score 0):

Wait ,so you need the part inside the href tag,right ?Say we have 
 `<a id="par1" href="#iNeedThisPart">¶</a>` , then do you want 'iNeedThisPart'?
If that is indeed what you want ,then you need to use the css query a[href] ,which would select all 'a' tags with 'href' attribute. The JSoup code for the same will be as follows:

```
public List<String> getTextWithinHrefAttribute(final File file) throws IOException{
    final List<String> hrefTexts = new ArrayList<>();
    final Document document=Jsoup.parse(file,"utf-8");
    final Elements ahrefs =document.select("a[href]");

    for(final Element ahref : ahrefs ){
        hrefTexts.add(ahref.attr("href"));
    }
    return hrefTexts;
}
```

I am assuming that you are parsing from a file, and not crawling  a web page.

Comment: No I need the MoreText part , not the text between enclosed href tags. Thank you for your reply